# Is there a method to convert SAP ABAP routines to SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, abap, sap-bw

I need to replicate a provider in SAP BW system to GCP Bigquery. I have all the underlying data sources for provider copied in BigQuery. To create the provider, I need to understand the ABAP routine determining condition of joins and logic for all data sources. Do we have any tool or method with which we can convert the ABAP routine to SQL, which I can then use in bigquery.

Comment: I guess, what you call an "ABAP routine", is a BW Expert, Start or End routine. ABAP and SQL (I guess you mean a SQL Script language) are both programming languages, for now there's no Artificial Intelligence able to convert from one programming language to another, if even possible to convert it at all.

Answer (score 3):

No. ABAP routines, as you name them, or ABAP SQL statements are written with a special SAP dialect of SQL called [OpenSql](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abenopen_sql_glosry.htm), which is unified for all databases. The implementation of one or another OpenSQL query on certain RDBMS and on certain platform may vary. So only manual way.